# How start migrations EF Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have several project in a solution. There is a dbContext in the Infrastructure project and I want to migrate, but I get an error. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it.

[image]

[image]

```
using Infrastructure.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Infrastructure
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<EventModel> Event { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(GetConnectionString());
        }

        private static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            const string databaseName = "myDb";
            const string databaseUser = "postgres";
            const string databasePass = "root";

            return $"Server=localhost;" +
                   $"database={databaseName};" +
                   $"uid={databaseUser};" +
                   $"pwd={databasePass};" +
                   $"pooling=true;";
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add constructor without parameters to class `ApplicationDbContext`.

It is clearly described in link on error image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#using-a-constructor-with-no-parameters